# Is there a way to increase an inquisitor's judgments per day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, inquisitor

I am playing a 6th level inquisitor in *Pathfinder*, and would like to take better advantage of their judgement and bane abilities.  I know that you can increase the bane abilities rounds per day with the extended bane and extra bane feats.  Is there a way to increase the amount of times per day that I can use my judgments? As of right now,  I can only use it twice per day.

Answer (score 4):

## There is none

Other than advancing levels in the [inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) class, there are no official ways to obtain more uses of the supernatural ability [judgment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Inquisitor/#TOC-Judgment-Su-).

The feat [**Judgment Surge**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/judgment-surge/) increases the efficacy of an inquisitor's judgments as if the creature's inquisitor class level were 3 higher, but the feat has no effect on the number of times per day that the ability can be activated.

I suspect that the reason that no such feat or magic item exists for increasing the number of judgments per day is *probably* that the ability judgement is *very* strong, and any such feat would automatically be the best choice every time it could be taken, but no developer has confirmed my suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1: Dip into a class that gets the judgment feature faster.

Normally, [Inquisitors](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) gain one additional daily judgment for every 3 levels beyond 1st (4, 7, 10, etc.). Instead of investing another 3 levels of Inquisitor, you could dip levels of another class for that extra judgment usage.

For example: The [Circuit Judge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/archetypes/paizo-cavalier-archetypes/circuit-judge/) Cavalier archetype gets 2 daily judgment uses, and 2 more for every 3 levels beyond 1st. They get twice as many judgments as an Inquisitor! However, they have fewer options and cannot benefit from multiple simultaneous judgment types (until 12th level), and this feature does not stack with your Inquisitor levels.

Another example: The [Gray Warden](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/gray-warden/) prestige class gains one daily "harsh judgment" at 2nd level, which stacks with an Inquisitor levels and functions as the judgment feature, but offers fewer options. The Zealot [Vigilante](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/vigilante/) can gain this feature via vigilante talents at 2nd and 4th levels. Thus a 6-level dip into Zealot Vigilante 4 / Gray Warden 2 could get you 3 more daily uses of judgment, whereas spending those 6 levels in Inquisitor would get you only 2 more.

While these methods increase the number of daily judgment uses, they have the obvious downside of losing spellcasting levels and other Inquisitor features.

#### Solution 2: Team up with a second Inquisitor.

Instead of multiclassing, you can indirectly get additional uses of judgment by benefiting from another [Inquisitor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor)'s judgment. First, take the [Leadership](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership/) feat (which requires 7th level) to get an Inquisitor cohort. The cohort's level would be, at most, equal to your level - 2.

Then, the cohort needs some way to share the benefits of their judgment with you. The cheapest and simplest method is the 1st level Inquisitor spell [*Lend Judgment*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lend-judgment/).

> That ally gains the benefit of one of your active judgments (as do you)... If you have multiple judgments active, the ally gains only one, chosen when you cast this spell.

If you have no judgments remaining, then the cohort could begin a judgment (swift action) and cast the spell (standard action). Then you would effectively have the benefits of an additional use of judgment. These bonuses may be smaller than the bonuses of your own judgments, although this can be mitigated if the cohort takes the [Judgment Surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/judgment-surge/) feat.

Eventually, once the cohort reaches 8th level (i.e., you are at least 10th level) and gets the Second Judgment class feature, they could take the [Shared Judgment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/shared-judgment/) feat. Using this feat lets them "split" multiple judgment effects across multiple allies.

> You can pronounce a single judgment and extend its effects to one adjacent ally instead of pronouncing a second judgment. Similarly, once you have the third judgment class feature, you can pronounce a single judgment and extend its effects to two adjacent allies instead of pronouncing a second and third judgment. Alternatively, once you have the third judgment class feature, you can pronounce two judgments and extend the effects of one judgment to one adjacent ally instead of pronouncing a third judgment.

For example, if your cohort could simultaneously use the Destruction and Justice judgments for themselves, then they could instead give you the Destruction judgment and they only get the Justice judgment for themselves. This works even if you depleted your own daily uses of judgment.

As a summary:

- *Lend Judgment* (spell) lets you duplicate one of your cohort's active judgments. Using it costs your cohort a standard action and one spell slot.
- Share Judgment (feat) lets you take one (or more) of your cohort's active judgments onto you. Using it requires no extra action, but the cohort gets fewer judgment benefits for themselves.

(Side note: Amusingly and confusingly, this implies that *Lend Judgment* involves sharing a benefit, while Share Judgment involves lending a benefit.)

Comment: Worth noting that the judgement granted by the Grey Warden or Zealot Vigilante is not the same as the inquisitor's judgement. You only stack levels to determine their effects, but it counts as a second ability that has a separate per-day usage. So if you multiclass into all 3, you have 3 pools of uses/day of different judgement abilities. Effectively, you get 2 extra uses per day, not 1, but these uses can only be used for those types of judgement listed on that ability, which are the same for the PrC and vigilante: destruction, piercing, purity, and smiting.

Comment: @ShadowKras Is my math wrong? Vigilante 4 / Grey Warden 2 dip would give +3 uses, whereas spending those 6 levels in Inquisitor would grant +2 uses. So dipping gives 3 - 2 = 1 more.

Comment: the total number of "judgement" uses is correct, but considering that they are three different abilities, you shouldnt stack them into the same pool.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will definitely take it into consideration, but I am currently playing an adventure path and have found out in the past as a GM running an adventure path, the leadership feat tends to over power the group especially if more than one PC takes the feat.